# How to update a Pod in iOS App Swift

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a pod file as below -

`# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project`

`platform :ios, '8.0'`

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

`target 'OSLMobile' do`

`pod 'AFNetworking'`

`pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'`

`end`

`target 'OSLMobileTests' do`

`pod 'AFNetworking'`

`pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'`

`end`

I want to update the library 'libPhoneNumber-iOS'. For this I am going in my project directory and typing 
`pod update libPhoneNumber-iOS`.

But this is giving me the error -

`[!] Unable to add a source with url`https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`named master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Can some on please help me how can I update `libPhoneNumber-iOS`?

Other details - XCode 8.0, Swift 2.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `pod init`

If you get `[!] Existing Podfile found in Directory`

Go to `~/.cocoapods/repos` and run `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

Then run your

`pod update libPhoneNumber-iOS`

[Reference](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293)

Comment: From which path should I run - ~/.cocoapods/repos?

Comment: You would `cd ~/.cocoapods/repos` to that path and then run `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

Answer (score 1):

Go to `~/.cocoapods/repos` and run

`git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

Referenced from [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293)

Comment: I am getting the error - xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)

Comment: You have two xcodes in your mac, you need to explicitly give the path of your Xcode using `xcode-select --switch`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify source.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!        
target 'OSLMobile' do 
pod 'AFNetworking'    
pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'    
end

target 'OSLMobileTests' do    
pod 'AFNetworking'    
pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'    
end
```

Also update your master repo before installing or updating the pods. You can update master repo with command in terminal.

> pod repo update

Answer (score 0):

iOS9:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, ‘9.0’

pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'

target 'OSLMobile' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for OSLMobile

target 'OSLMobileTests' do
 inherit! :search_paths
 # Pods for testing
end

target 'OSLMobileUITests' do
 inherit! :search_paths
 # Pods for testing
end
```

end